# How to construct a tuple from an array

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, c++14, variadic-templates

I am designing a C++ library that reads a CSV file of reported data from some experiment and does some aggregation and outputs a pgfplots code. I want to make the library as generic and easy to use as possible. I also want to isolate it from the data types that are represented in the CSV file and leave the option to user to parse each column as she desires. I also want to avoid Boost Spirit Qi or other heavy duty parser.

The simple solution I have is for the user to create a type for each column, with a constructor that takes "char *". The constructor does its own parsing for the value it is given, which is one cell from the data. The user then passes me a list of types; the schema, representing the types in a line of data. I use this type list to create a tuple, in which every member of the tuple is responsible for parsing itself.

The problem now is how to initialise (construct) this tuple. Dealing with tuples is of course not straightforward since iterating over their elements is mostly a compile-time operation. I used Boost Fusion at first to achieve this task. However, the function I used (transform) although might take a tuple as input (with the appropriate adapter), it does not seem to return a tuple. I need the return value to be a tuple so some other code can use it as an associative type-to-value container (access it by type via `std::get<T>`), while using only standard tools, that is, without using Boost. So I had to convert whatever Fusion's transform returned into std::tuple.

My question is how to avoid this conversion, and better yet how to avoid Boost Fusion completely.

A simple solution that comes to mind is to use the constructor of std::tuple, and somehow pass each element its respective "const *" that it needs to construct. However, while this is possible using some complicated template-based enumeration techniques, I am wondering if there is a straightforward "parameter-pack"-like approach, or an even simpler way to pass the values to the constructors of the individual elements of a tuple.

To clarify what I am seeking, kindly take a look at this following code.

```
    #include <cstdio>
    #include <array>
    template <typename...> struct format {};
    template <typename...> struct file_loader {};
    template <typename... Format>
    struct
    file_loader<format<Format...> > {
        void load_file() {
            size_t strsize = 500u;
            char *str = new char[strsize]();

            auto is = fopen("RESULT","r");
            /* example of RESULT:
                 dataset2,0.1004,524288
                 dataset1,0.3253,4194304
            */
            while(getline(&str, &strsize, is) >= 0) {
                std::array<char*, 3> toks{};
                auto s = str;
                int i = 2;
                while(i --> 0)
                    toks[i] = strsep (&s, ",");
                toks[2] = strsep (&s, ",\n");

                std::tuple<Format...> the_line{ /* toks */ } ; // <-- HERE
                //// current solution:
                // auto the_line{
                // as_std_tuple( // <-- unnecessary conversion I'd like to avoid
                //  boost::fusion::transform(boost::fusion::zip(types, toks), boost::fusion::make_fused( CAST() ))
                //  )};


                // do something with the_line
            }
        }
    };

    #include <string>
    class double_type {
    public:
        double_type() {}
        double_type(char const *token) { } // strtod
    };
    class int_type {
    public:
        int_type() {}
        int_type(char const *token) { } // strtoul
    };

    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        file_loader< format< std::string,
                             double_type,
                             int_type > >
        {}.load_file();


        return 0;
    }
```

I've highlighted the interesting line as "HERE" in a comment.

My question precisely is:

> Is there a way to construct a std::tuple instance (of heterogeneous
>   types, each of which is implicitly convertible from "char *") with
>   automatic storage duration (on the stack) from a `std::array<char *, N>`, 
>   where N equals the size of that tuple?

The answer I am seeking should

1. Avoid Boost Fusion
2. (Simplicity condition) Avoid using more than 5 lines of boilerplate template-based enumeration code
3. Alternatively, shows why this is not possible to do in the C++14 standard

The answer can use C++17 constructs, I wouldn't mind.

Thank you,

Comment: It would be good to know whether Fusion's transform can return std::tuple directly.

Comment: `while(i --> 0)` Please don't do this. You'll scare the children. :)

Comment: @erip I am not actually using this. In my real code I am using boost irange. I just didn't want to bring all the non standard stuff and includes from my code here. Wouldn't you think irange would be scarier?

Comment: I feel like you could expand `toks` using variadic templates and forward it to `std::tie`. Just a thought. :)

Comment: @erip I thought of that but it is not clear to me how to expand toks using variadic templates.

Comment: In c++17, couldn't you just pass the array to std::apply?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

As with all questions involving `std::tuple`, use [`index_sequence`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/integer_sequence) to give you a parameter pack to index the array with:

```
template <class... Formats, size_t N, size_t... Is>
std::tuple<Formats...> as_tuple(std::array<char*, N> const& arr,
                                std::index_sequence<Is...>)
{
    return std::make_tuple(Formats{arr[Is]}...);
}

template <class... Formats, size_t N,
          class = std::enable_if_t<(N == sizeof...(Formats))>>
std::tuple<Formats...> as_tuple(std::array<char*, N> const& arr)
{
    return as_tuple<Formats...>(arr, std::make_index_sequence<N>{});
}
```

Which you would use as:

```
std::tuple<Format...> the_line = as_tuple<Format...>(toks);
```

Comment: Very nice indeed. +1 for the enable_if sanity check :) !

Comment: I would probably `static_assert` inside instead. But +1.

Comment: @T.C. What do you consider as the rule between when to use `static_assert()` and when to use `enable_if`?

Comment: @Barry Anything someone might reasonably want to use `is_detected` (or the concept equivalent) on => `enable_if` so that we don't lie. Otherwise, `static_assert` gives nicer  error messages. Of course, it's kind of subjective.

Comment: Just a minor nitpick, perhaps it could have been made a bit more generic for the array type ([e.g.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6e20303d0c95c344))

Comment: is this C++14 compliant only ? i just tested it and it didn't work with C++11. if it is the case, can you edit/mention it in the answer... thx !

Comment: @Vtik Yes, there are several things in here that are C++14 library features. They are all implementable in C++11 though, and there are lots of resources on this site to help you do that.