# Turn C string literal into std::integer_sequence at compile-time with C++17

Tags: c++, c++17

Is it possible to write a construct that turns any C string literal `"XY..."` into a type `std::integer_sequence<char, 'X', 'Y', ...>` at compile time? I really want a character pack, not a `std::array`.

Something like

```
using MyStringType = magic_const_expr("MyString");
```

A nice approach using the literal operator was demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28209546/9213844) but unfortunately it requires a non-standard compiler extension.

Comment: Would you be okay using the syntax `using MyStringType = decltype(MyString_some_ud_suffix);`

Comment: Another option is to use something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37029886/how-to-construct-a-tuple-from-an-array) to convert the array to a tuple and then you can use the tuple to build an `integer_sequence`

Comment: The accepted answer to the question you linked contains a link [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15858141/conveniently-declaring-compile-time-strings-in-c) which seems to have some solutions, such as [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15863804/189205) (it predates `std::integer_sequence` but the idea is the same).

Comment: @interjay, that solution you linked relies on storing the literal as a global constant and feeding the address into a class template. I am looking for a solution that keeps the literal on the stack and compiles it eventually away.

Comment: @NathanOliver you mean `using MyStringType = decltype("MyString"_some_ud_suffix)` (note the ")? That would be fine as long it works with plain C++17 without extensions.

Comment: @RichardW The C++ language does not support `"MyString"_some_ud_suffix`  You would have to do it without the `"` like `MyString_some_ud_suffix`.

Comment: I started hacking around a bit and came up with [this](https://godbolt.org/z/bMGqGrzro).  You need to declare a variable with this though to get the integer sequence type, so it's not as nice, but could be useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this might do it:

```
template <size_t N, typename F, size_t... indexes>
constexpr auto make_seq_helper(F f, std::index_sequence<indexes...> is) {
    return std::integer_sequence<char, (f()[indexes])...>{};
}

template <typename F>
constexpr auto make_seq(F f) {
    constexpr size_t N = f().size();
    using indexes = std::make_index_sequence<N>;
    return make_seq_helper<N>(f, indexes{});
};


template<const char* str>
struct IntegerSequenceFromString {
    
    private:
    constexpr static auto value = make_seq([](){return std::string_view{str}; });
    
    public:
    using type = decltype(value);
};
```

Usage would then be:

```
 constexpr static const char str[] = "lala";
 IntegerSequenceFromString<str>::type i{};
```

[Here is a live example of it working.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1100439e93793f6b)

I am sure, there is a way to reduce some of this extra stuff as well, but from the assembly, it looks like we don't generate any real runtime variables: https://godbolt.org/z/f65cjGfzn

Comment: You can get rid of the extraneous `constexpr static const char str[] =` and define the type in one line, see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/eojEsno7b).

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. The question is tagged C++17 though.

Comment: @user17732522 yeah didn't notice, my bad

Comment: Thanks. It's a pity though that i have to define `str` as a separate variable (C++17).